# Zywall IPSEC config for remote shares using ipsecuritas

Tags: vpn, ipsec

I have a Zywall USG 20 using IPsec. It works and connects fine however I can only access the zywall its self. Traffic does not route to other computers on the subnet. In my case I need to access linux and windows shares. Not sure if I have my subnets setup incorrectly or my vpn client configured incorrectly. I used both ipsecuritas and vpntracker (osx client) and identical results. I could access the zywall but not the computers on the subnet. I have been at this for hours so im sure its something simple im over looking but im not sure what I should provide. Client and Remote use different subnets, im connecting via IP not domain names. Zywall zone policy is the same as the computers on the subnet. I cant ping anything but the zywall. I cant force all my traffic over the vpn however I dont know IPSec well enough to know if my hardware can support it. Would prefer that since its intended for a travel laptop. Advice?

Enpoints set in ipsecuritas:
Local side, Mode: Auto (tried host and forcing an ip as well)
Remote side, Network, 10.2.0.0/24

Client subnet is: 10.0.0.1/24
Remote subnet is: 10.2.0.0/24